# Как правильно инициализировать свойство класса, представляющее собой класс? C++

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, инициализация

Есть собственный класс Terminal. Его свойство window - это переменная типа Window:

```
class Terminal:
{
private:
    Window window;
public:
    Terminal(int x, int y);
}
```

Как правильно объявить и инициализировать ее в конструкторе? Ведь она уже объявлена. Попытался сделать через прямую инициализацию:

```
Terminal::Terminal(int x, int y) {
    window(x, y);
}
```

Выдало ошибку. Как вариант - использовать копирующую инициализацию:

```
window = Window(x, y)
```

Но я читал, что использование копирующей инициализации для объектов (особенно тяжелых) - плохо. Как правильно провести инициализацию в таком случае? Нужно ли применять список инициализаторов или это неправильный подход?

Comment: *"использование копирующей инициализации для объектов (особенно тяжелых) - плохо"* - где вы вычитываете эту чепуху? Копирующая инициализация - просто один из вариантов синтаксиса инициализации, особенностью которого является рассмотрение не explicit конструкторов. Начиная с С++17 она фактически больше не нужна и присутствует в языке для обратной совместимости.

Comment: @user7860670 к сожалению, многие источники устарели :) Возможно проблема в этом. Читал, что при копирующей инициализации происходит нечто вроде создания объекта класса, а потом копирование его в переменную

Comment: Что-то у меня сомнения, что `window = Window(x, y)` - копирующая инициализация, а не обычное присваивание...

Comment: @Harry думаю, вы правы. Сейчас разбирался, оказывается при создании объекта классы-свойства не просто объявляются, я вызывается их конструктор по умолчанию, если не указан другой. Следовательно в теле конструктора класса Terminal переменная window - это уже инициализированная переменная, а = - это присваивание в данной случае.

Comment: На то и намекал :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так:

```
Terminal::Terminal(int x, int y):window(x, y)
{
}
```

Учтите - в каком порядке бы вы их (инициализаторы) не записали, порядок инициализации - базовые конструкторы, а затем члены в порядке появления их в объявлении класса.